# FBStreamDialog doesn't show attachment

Tags: iphone, facebook

I use the simple FBStreamDialog example in my iPad app:

FBStreamDialog* pDialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
 pDialog.delegate = self;

pDialog.userMessagePrompt = @"Example prompt";
 pDialog.attachment = @"{\"name\":\"Facebook Connect for iPhone\",\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone\",\"caption\":\"Caption\",\"description\":\"Description\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://img40.yfrog.com/img40/5914/iphoneconnectbtn.jpg\",\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone/\"}],\"properties\":{\"another link\":{\"text\":\"Facebook home page\",\"href\":\"http://www.facebook.com\"}}}";

NSLog(@"prompt: %@", pDialog.userMessagePrompt);
 NSLog(@"attachment: %@", pDialog.attachment);

[pDialog show];

NSLogs are OK.
The problem is that neither message prompt nor attachment are shown in FBStreamDialog.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in simulator. It works on device.